# Best practice to associate icons with Arralist<String>?

Tags: android, arraylist, icons

I have a set of cca 50 icons of sports in my android app, and I need to have a function to which I hand over name of sport and the function returns sport icon.

Right now I deal with this problem like this:

```
public static int getSportIcon(String sport){
    if(sport != null) {
        switch (sport) {
            case "Swimming": {
                return R.drawable.swimming;
            }
            case "Bicycling": {
                return R.drawable.bicycling;
            }
            case "Football": {
                return R.drawable.football;
            }
            case "Badminton": {
                return R.drawable.badminton;
            }
            case "Hockey": {
                return R.drawable.hockey;
            }
            case "Skiing": {
                return R.drawable.skiing;
            }
            case "TableTennis": {
                return R.drawable.table_tennis;
            }
            case "Tennis": {
                return R.drawable.tennis;
            }
            case "Volleyball": {
                return R.drawable.volleyball;
            }
            case "Basketball":
                return R.drawable.basketball;
            default: {
                return R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(sport.toLowerCase(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

This will get a drawable with the matching string name.  I'd cache the result somewhere, so you don't have to constantly use this (its not the fastest function, especially if used while drawing).

Answer (score 2):

one can also define associative `String` & `Drawable` in `array.xml` alike ...to link the strings is more convenient, else one needs to maintain these arrays for each language. optionally one can add a `name=""` attribute to the `item` nodes (this string would be the same in any language, it just enables the lookup by name - vs. the lookup by index).

```
<string-array name="sports_string">
    <item>@string/swimming</item>
    <item>@string/bicycling</item>
    <item>@string/football</item>
    <item>@string/badminton</item>
    <item>@string/hockey</item>
    <item>@string/skiing</item>
    <item>@string/table_tennis</item>
    <item>@string/tennis</item>
    <item>@string/volleyball</item>
    <item>@string/basketball</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="sports_drawable">
    <item>@drawable/swimming</item>
    <item>@drawable/bicycling</item>
    <item>@drawable/football</item>
    <item>@drawable/badminton</item>
    <item>@drawable/hockey</item>
    <item>@drawable/skiing</item>
    <item>@drawable/table_tennis</item>
    <item>@drawable/tennis</item>
    <item>@drawable/volleyball</item>
    <item>@drawable/basketball</item>
</string-array>
```

one can even reference whole arrays, alike `<item>@array/swimming</item>`, so that one can have one array per item, which is probably the most convenient, so that it would become:

```
<string-array name="swimming">
    <item name="title">@string/swimming</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/swimming</item>
</string-array>
...
<string-array name="sports">
    <item>@array/swimming</item>
    <item>@array/bicycling</item>
    <item>@array/football</item>
    <item>@array/badminton</item>
    <item>@array/hockey</item>
    <item>@array/skiing</item>
    <item>@array/table_tennis</item>
    <item>@array/tennis</item>
    <item>@array/volleyball</item>
    <item>@array/basketball</item>
</string-array>
```

in order to assign those associative arrays to a `BaseAdapter` ...

```
public class SomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<SomeItem> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    public SomeAdapter(Context context, @ArrayRes int strings, @ArrayRes int drawables) {

        /* these TypedArray hold the relevant resource ids */
        TypedArray resString = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(strings);
        TypedArray resDrawable = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(drawables);

        /* check if both TypedArray have the same length. */
        if(resString.length() != resDrawable.length()) {return false;}

        /* populate this.mItems in a loop,  whatever type these items may have. */
        for (int i=0; i < resString.length(); i++) {

            /* checking if there is a resource */
            int resIdTitle = resString.getResourceId(i, -1);
            if (resIdTitle < 0) {continue;}

            int resIdIcon = resDrawable.getResourceId(i, -1);
            if (resIdIcon < 0) {continue;}

            ...
        }

        /* TypedArray needs to be recycled */
        resString.recycle();
        resDrawable.recycle();
    }
}
```

think that a single array one can even directly assigned to a `AppCompatSpinner` in XML, but when having more than one input array or when the input array has more than one dimension, one somehow has to process that, in order to convert to objects of the desired classes - when using the alternate array structure (using the `@array` reference), one just needs to nest the loops, but it works about the same.

accessing the `TypedArray` only once, eg. when instancing an Adapter, might be quicker than to look up every single one item by name (because these methods most likely just load, scan & must do recycle internally, as well) - therefore `.getIdentifier()` appears useful for single resource look ups, in order to translate the `name` attribute to `resId`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a list from String and drawables. Then set each icon by index.

```
 <string-array name="list_menu">
    <item>title1</item>
    <item>title2</item>
    <item>title3</item></<string-array >

  <integer-array name="icons_menus">
    <item>@drawable/title1</item>
    <item>@drawable/title2</item>
    <item>@drawable/title3</item></integer-array>
```